# Web crawler: How to find and store links by HTML tag attributes?

Tags: html, algorithm, web-crawler

Apologies if something like this has already been answered.

I am attempting to implement an algorithm idea of mine and would like to be pointed in the right direction.

The algorithm would function as follows:

1. Retrieve the HTML source page for the website
2. Search through this HTML page and store any links within an anchor tag, `<a>`, with a specific class attribute, e.g. If class="videos", then store href="this video" from `<a>`
3. Repeat both these steps for the newly stored links up to 5 degrees of separation from the original URL.

I would then like to output the data like a family tree of URLs, but let's not get ahead of myself.

The main issue is that I am a novice to practical programming and am having trouble figuring out where to start. So, I'm asking for some advice on the following,

- What language should I use? (I know some java, some android and some javascript.)
- What are the best practices regarding this kind of program? (So I can avoid stepping on a website's toes.)
- What are the main problems I may encounter when trying to implement this algorithm?
- Any tips and tricks?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of crawlers out there, in variety of languages. [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is fairly simple to use yet powerful enough.

Comment: Thanks, amit. I hadn't come across Scrapy during my google searches.